# Visual Studio 2017 minify on save

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, minify, web-essentials

Can anyone explain how to minify files on save. The extension Web Essentials used to work perfectly in earlier versions of VS and used to make life easy. Now it just won't work.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension but it doesn't work. Right-clicking on the CSS file in the solution gives the option to Re-Bundle file that doesn't work. I have tried building the application after making changes and that doesn't work.[image]

Any tips or things to try would be appreciated. I know I can copy the text and minify with other tools but that makes things take longer than they really should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that if the minifier is not working it is because there is an error in my CSS file that is not acceptable to VS.

It is hard to notice because the error only shows in the error list and there is no obvious alert for it like other code errors. I suggest looking to see if there is a CSS error in the error list and then correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler and minifier uses the old non maintained [NUglify](https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify) minifier, which doesn't support modern syntax constructs of both CSS and JavaScript.

Use NodeJS based tools instead and add them as a build step in your `.csproj` file. For example, I have this task in my project file:

```
<Target Name="Compile Typescript" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
</Target>
```

And in my `package.json` file, I have:

```
{
"name": "NAME",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "DESCRIPTION",
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel Scripts -d wwwroot/scripts --extensions .ts",
    "watch": "babel Scripts -d wwwroot/scripts --extensions .ts -w"
},
"author": "AUTHOR",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.2"
}
}
```

Which uses [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile and minify Typescript files.